# Wet dream and sperm

Tags: salat, taharah, self-purification

Salam, if I have a wet dream and the sperm only slightly stains the trousers am I required to change the bedding as well? I also do my ghusl in the morning as our bathroom is freezing cold during the night and our shower makes a lot of noise. Should i do my ghusl anyway jazakallah khair

Comment: You have actually asked about 8 questions and most of them have similar topics please check the site for similar questions first, then ask or explain why you think your question was not addressed earlier. Here you've posted a multi-question post one of the questions is clearly answered on the site and I'd even say that the second could have at least been addressed. We don't look forward to have 10 or more question duplicates. And multi-questions can't be marked as such!

Comment: My bad... I’ll make sure to double check before I post anything in the future. Thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 1):

In fact your question is a [multi-question post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions) which is of a kind that you should avoid:

Your first question mainly is covered in:
[How to purify a carpet if I don't remember were the impurity is?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62384/i-dont-remember-were-the-impurity-is):
you must be in a tahir state not your bedding: This means in order to pray your body and all clothes you wear and the surface you pray on must be free from any najasah (impurity). Please read the linked post. Especially the quote about "najasah" contamination could be relevant!
Also note that whether sperms are najis or not is discussed among scholars.
See also: [Washing cloths after a wet dream or getting conatminated with sperm by some other means](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49615/washing-cloths-after-a-wet-dream-or-getting-conatminated-with-sperm-by-some-othe).

Your second question:
The whole question is off-topic because we are not a fatwa site. And therefore we can't clearly state whether you may be allowed to perform tayyamum instead and under what conditions this would be allowed.

However be aware that the shower making noise is no valid excuse for not performing ghusl.
While it might be allowed to perform tayyamum due to coldness in case of fear of death if one doesn't take enough precautions.
See also: [What's the alternative to purify after intercourse?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61731/whats-the-alternative-to-purify-after-intercourse/61734#61734)